# pandoc ignores yaml options

Tags: pdf, yaml, latex, pandoc

I have trouble with the yaml header in a markdown file.

I would like to use the yaml header. At the moment I copy/paste the pandoc command with all cli arguments each time I need to process my file. It would be better if it is possible to use the yaml header for the same arguments.

The `test.md`:

```
---
from: markdown
to: pdf
output-file: foo.pdf
table-of-contents: true
number-sections: true
shift-heading-level-by: -1
title:  'This is the title'
subtitle: "This is the subtitle"
author:
- Author One
- Author Two
- Author Three
---

## First header

This is the first header

## Second header

Second header with math:

$$
c^2 = a^2 + b^2
$$
```

It does not work to run `pandoc test.md`. It retuns the HTML in the terminal, instead of the `output-file`.

Some commands do not work:

- `table-of-contents: true` does not work. CLI --table-of-contents does work. As alternative `toc: true` does work.
- `number-sections: true` does not work. CLI `--number-sections` does work. As alternative `numbersections: true` does work.

Some never work:

- `output-file`
- `to`
- `pdf-engine`
- `mainfont`
- `template: my_template.latex` (stored in local file)
- `shift-heading-level-by: -1`

In the command line the `template`, `pdf-engine` and `shift-header-level-by: -1` does work.

```
pandoc .\README.md -o readme.pdf --template=my_template.latex --pdf-engine=xelatex  --shift-heading-level-by=-1
```

The yaml for the document that worked looks like:

```
mainfont: Segoe UI
numbersections: yes
```

EDIT:
I used https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#general-writer-options-1 to find the yaml options, and I run pandoc version:

```
pandoc.exe 3.1.9
Features: +server +lua
Scripting engine: Lua 5.4
User data directory: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2023 John MacFarlane. Web: https://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is no
warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.
```

Comment: You probably want a [defaults file](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL#defaults-files) or a pandoc-based processor like [Quarto](https://quarto.org). The reason for pandoc's behavior is security.

Comment: Could you elaborate about the defaults file? I do not understand how to use it, and what the difference is with the templates (which you can see with `pandoc -D`?